# Terraform autoscale rule to "scale instance to specific instance count"

Tags: azure, terraform

The Azure portal provides the capability to scale instances based on a specific metric or "scale to specific instance count".

I understand scaling based on a metric, but I don't see a tag to "scale instance to specific count". What snippet of terraform code would demonstrate an autoscaling rule base on specific instance count?

Answer (score 0):

The [azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/monitor_autoscale_setting.html) resource should implement that. The resource takes `profile` blocks as parameters where the `capacity` can be defined.

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_autoscale_setting" "test" {
  name                = "myAutoscaleSetting"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.location}"
  target_resource_id  = "${azurerm_virtual_machine_scale_set.test.id}"

  profile {
    name = "defaultProfile"

    capacity {
      default = 1
      minimum = 1
      maximum = 10
    }
    [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

at the moment it seems there is not the opportunity to set autoscaling with "scale to specific instance count" option with terraform.
the metric_trigger child is mandatory for rule.

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3870